# If I assign a foreign key to a new column I want to delete the previous data column with the same foreign key in the same table

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a user table and a rooms table. the rooms have been assigned to the users as foreign key. I want to delete the room assigned to the user when I insert a new user with the same room.

Comment: *I have a user table and a rooms table. the rooms have been assigned to the users as foreign key.* Provide this as CREATE TABLE scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a check before you're inserting new record that if the rooms exists on any user or not if yes run the delete query simple.